# Doing a postBack in a unload event on firefox causes to stay always in the same page

Tags: firefox, refresh, postback

Using c# .net

Hi, I´m trying to do a postBack on a unload event, in google chrome the currently script works fine

```
window.onbeforeunload = function () {
            __doPostBack('<%= pararThread.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") %>');
        }

for internet explorer and other, I had to use Jquery
        $(window).unload(function () {
            __doPostBack('<%= pararThread.ClientID.Replace("_", "$") %>');
        });
```

So far, so good, but, only in Firefox, the page is doing the postback, but it no longer goes to another page, Example, **if a click on a Link, it will fire the event unLoad, it will do the post back, but the page will refresh and will not reach the link**.

**Ps: I´m doing this postBack because I need to stop a Thread that os runing on the server.**

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code snippet in your .master page or any other appropiate page just before the `</body>` tag:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
<!--
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
var theform;
if (window.navigator.appName.toLowerCase().indexOf("microsoft") > -1) {
theform = document.aspnetForm;
}
else {
theform = document.forms["aspnetForm"];
}
theform.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget.split("$").join(":");
theform.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
theform.submit();
}
// -->
</script>
```

Replace 'aspnetForm' with your own.

Comment: I Tryed, I putted what you wrote in MasterPage right before the </body>. But didn´t work. I did debug in firefox, and it passes inside the function and executes the {else {
theform = document.forms["aspnetForm"]; But didn´t work! It still not reaching the link I clicked, or the address that I wrote in the address bar! But thanks for the try!
}}